# Stuck with WordPress ACF plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am hitting a bit of a brick wall with a simple WordPress problem. I am using the ACF plugin and can't seem to get it to show the field on the pages. My page.php file looks like this:

```
  <?php get_header(); ?>

  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>



      <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <!-- Starting the loop -->  
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <div <?php post_class() ?>>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
          </div>

        <?php the_content(''); ?>


        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <h2><?php the_field('bottom'); ?></h2>
        <?php else : ?>

            <h1>Nothing Found</h1>
            <p>Sorry but we cant find anything</p>

        <?php endif; ?>


        </div>
      </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It's really simple as far as I can tell. Was just doing this as an exercise to get a handle on ACF before using it for something more technical and I'm stumped!

The field is 'bottom' and I just want to stick the text in there after the loop.

[Screen shot of the custom field in the plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOdsc.png)

I'm guessing this is going to be something really simple but can't seem to find an answer anywhere!

Comment: Are you certain that you've given the field a value for this specific page, otherwise you can add the postId of the targeted page as a second parameter to the function.

Comment: Thanks mate... it really was that simplet. Cheers for your help, just needed to click update on the pages.... duhhh :o)

Comment: Glad you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posting a solution on behalf of the OP)*.

The answer is simple, as expected. I hadn't clicked update on the specific pages after adding the custom field template! Simple but no less frustrating. Thanks for the help.